# AudioKitEX not compiling

Tags: swift, build, swift-package-manager, audiokit

I have returned to a project that has lain fallow for 2+ years while I got seriously caught up in 3D printing. At the time I left it I was using AudioKit 4.x. I'm doing the update to V5. Now I have package dependencies set up with

```
AudioKit v5-main
AudioKitEX 5.6.0
KissFFT 1.0.0
SoundpipeAudioKit 5.6.1
```

A whole bunch of AudioKitEX files are kicking off errors. The first of which is from AudioKitAU.swift, (x) Missing required module 'soundpipe'.

In other files I am getting a lot of messages like

```
public var connections: [Node] { [] }      (x) Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'connections'
```

This seems like some kind of version mismatch, but I've looked at the package files the dependencies seem to be OK.

Xcode and MacOS are all up to date.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The main (sic) problem here is that the branch for AudioKit is called main, not main-v5. I had to clean the build folder before the package seemed to be properly integrated.

I now have other problems but this question is no longer relevant.